# Hong Kong visa after rejected Pre Arrival Registration - Indian citizen

Tags: indian-citizens, hong-kong, e-visas

I am an Indian citizen and have plans to travel to Hong Kong on work in a couple of months. I applied for the 14-day Pre Arrival Registration (PAR) but the application was unsuccessful (from forums online I have learnt that the system fails everyone who had their passport issued from my city). Now I must apply for a visa.

I have 2 questions:

1. Are my odds of getting the visa are at risk because of the unsuccessful PAR? Anyone who was denied a PAR and later got the visa?
2. From the document requirements online, it looks like I only need to submit a photocopy of my passport and not the original. Since the visa takes about 4 weeks to be issued, I would like to keep my original passport so I can travel while the visa is processing. Could someone please confirm that this is correct?

Comment: There are many on TripAdvisor who had an unsuccessful attempt at PAR but later got their visa. It is just a time consuming process but there is no such thing that PAR rejection leads to a visa rejection.

Answer (score 3):

> **Are my odds of getting the visa are at risk because of the unsuccessful PAR? Anyone who was denied a PAR and later got the visa?**

On the [Hong Kong GOV website](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/press/press-releases/20161212.html) it states:

> In case pre-arrival registration is unsuccessful, Indian nationals shall apply to the Immigration Department directly for an entry visa if they intend to visit Hong Kong.

I imagine that the government will not list this advice if it is impossible to get a visa after rejection.

Additionally, from this [Trip Advisor thread](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294217-i1496-k11862711-Hong_Kong_Pre_Arrival_registration_Unsuccessful_for_Indian-Hong_Kong.html) we see a few people who got accepted after rejection.

> **From the document requirements online, it looks like I only need to submit a photocopy of my passport and not the original. Since the visa takes about 4 weeks to be issued, I would like to keep my original passport so I can travel while the visa is processing. Could someone please confirm that this is correct?**

Visa applications for Hong Kong have to be made at the Immigration Department as Hong Kong has no embassies.

The [documents page](http://kolkata.china-consulate.org/eng/lsqw/t1229853.htm) states:

> Photocopy of applicant's passport.

Therefore, you can travel as your original passport isn’t required.